# What is the correct usage of capybara's within method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec-rails

For feature examples for the footer I've used this code:

```
feature 'in footer' do
    scenario "has a Copyright text" do
      within('footer') {
        expect(page).to have_content "Copyright"
      }
    end

    scenario "has navigation bar" do
      within('footer') {
        expect(page).to have_selector 'nav ul li'
      }
    end

    scenario "has a link for 'About'" do
      within('footer') {
        expect(page).to have_link 'About', href: '#'
      }
    end
end
```

If you look closely I repeated the "within" in each scenario and this conflicts with dryness of code.

I do not want to include all expectation in one scenario because I want an explanation for each of them.

What is the best method for using the within method in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to dry up the use of #within and still have multiple scenarios.  Someone might try to use an around filter, but because of the ordering of around and before/after filters it's not really going to work.  You can get what you're looking for without using #within, by finding the footer in a before block and then expect off that

```
before do
  visit('my page')
  @footer = find('footer')
end

scenario 'blah blah' do
  expect(@footer).to have_content('...')
end
```

I will say that writing feature tests only to check for a line of text on the page is not great practice.  Feature tests have a lot of overhead, and checking for a line of text thats not dependent on any user actions is really more suited to a view test rather than feature (You can still use Capybaras matchers in view tests).  Feature tests should be for testing larger behaviors in the system.

Comment: Thank you Tom. could you please explain some difference between view tests and feature tests? I thought these are same :|

Comment: by the way I asked a separate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35258592/is-there-any-difference-between-feature-test-and-view-test

Comment: +1 for "writing feature tests only to check for a line of text on the page is not great practice" ...especicially when "checking for a line of text that's not dependent on any user actions.

Answer (score 1):

You could create one method to do eliminate the repetition of the within method.

For example:

```
feature 'footer' do
  scenario 'footer has copyright text, navigation bar and link for about' do
    within('footer') {
       expect(page).to have_content "Copyright"
       expect(page).to have_selector 'nav ul li'
       expect(page).to have_link 'About', href: '#'
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you. but I want a separate explanation for each of them

Comment: do the capybara methods not provide enough explanation? `to have_content "Copyright"` is relatively descriptive. I'm not sure that having "has a copyright text" adds much of an explanation.

Comment: when you run examples with -f d switches of rspec command capybara's method does not apear, right? I want that explanation which print on the shell.

Comment: I edited my answer to include more descriptive text in the scenario method so that you will see the information when the tests run.

Comment: haha... this way is a trickish and acceptable  way.  Edit: the principle is to use short description for examples