# Is there any difference between a feature spec and a view spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, bdd, rspec-rails

I had a question about within dryness in Capybara [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35255786/what-is-the-correct-usage-of-within-method-in-capybara/35257760#35257760). Tom answered perfectly and in his answer he mentioned:

> Feature tests should be for testing larger behaviours in the system.

Is there a difference between a feature spec and a view spec in Ruby on Rails? If possible explain it with some example please.
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, feature and view specs are quite different. The first is a full integration test and the second tests a view in isolation.

A **feature spec** uses a headless browser to test the entire system from the outside just like a user uses it. It exercises code, database, views and Javascript too, if you use the right headless browser and turn on Javascript.

Unlike other types of rspec-rails spec, feature specs are defined with the `feature` and `scenario` methods.

Feature specs, and only feature specs, use all of Capybara's functionality, including `visit`, methods like `fill_in` and `click_button`, and matchers like `have_text`.

There are plenty of examples in [the rspec-rails documentation for feature specs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-4/docs/feature-specs/feature-spec). Here's a quick one:

```
feature "Questions" do
  scenario "User posts a question" do
    visit "/questions/ask"
    fill_in "title" with "Is there any difference between a feature spec and a view spec?"
    fill_in "question" with "I had a question ..."
    click_button "Post Your Question"
    expect(page).to have_text "Is there any difference between a feature spec and a view spec?"
    expect(page).to have_text "I had a question"
  end
end
```

A **view spec** just renders a view in isolation, with template variables provided by the test rather than by controllers.

Like other types of rspec-rails spec, view specs are defined with the `describe` and `it` methods. One assigns template variables with `assign`,  renders the view with `render` and gets the results with `rendered`.

The only Capybara functionality used in view specs is the matchers, like `have_text`.

There are plenty of examples in [the rspec-rails documentation of view specs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-4/docs/view-specs/view-spec). Here's a quick one:

```
describe "questions/show" do
  it "displays the question" do
    assign :title, "Is there any difference between a feature spec and a view spec?"
    assign :question, "I had a question"
    render

    expect(rendered).to match /Is there any difference between a feature spec and a view spec\?/
    expect(rendered).to match /I had a question/
  end
end
```

Comment: Just to clarify one small error here - while Capybara is not used to drive any actions in a view test, it's matchers are available by default so  things like  `expect(rendered).to have_text('I had a question')`  or `expect(rendered).to have_css('#my_box.some_class')`  will work